# ui-router templateProvider and factory

Tags: angular-ui-router

I'm having trouble using the templateProvider with my specific factory:

here's the factory code:

```
FlatView.service('BDParameters',['$http','$q',function($http,$q){

    var deferred = $q.defer();
     $http({method:'POST',data:{dimensionpassed:dimension},url:Routing.generate('_NRtworks_globalUtilsFunctions_getSetBDParameters')}).success(function(result){
         deferred.resolve(result); 
      });                

     return deferred.promise;                     
}]);
```

the factory is done this way so it's loaded when the page loads, so the data is available for all controllers.

and here's the states config:

```
FlatView.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("");

    $stateProvider
      .state('flatView', {
          url:"",

          views: {
              'main': {
                  controller:"flatViewElementList",
                  templateUrl:Routing.generate('_NRtworks_FlatView_elementList') 
              },
              'discrimSelector': {
                  templateProvider:['BDParameters','$http',function(BDParameters,$http){
                    BDParameters.then(function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        if(result["selectorList"] === 0)
                        {
                            return "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $http.get(Routing.generate('_NRtworks_FlatView_DiscrimSelector')).success(function(data)
                            {
                                return data;
                            });                           
                        }
                    });
                    return "that's actually returned";
                  }]                                                                     
              }
          }
      });    
});
```

As you can see what's returned isn't what I want (which is in the if). And given how my factory is made I can't see how I could change my code to make it work. Do you ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did a simple mistake on how to handle the $q.

You must return the call of the factory, and of the $http.
Plus the data returned by the $http is an object, we need to access data to make it work. Here's the code:

```
$stateProvider
.state('flatView', {
  url:"",

  views: {
      'main': {
          controller:"flatViewElementList",
          templateUrl:Routing.generate('_NRtworks_FlatView_elementList') 
      },
      'discrimSelector': {
          templateProvider:['BDParameters','$http',function(BDParameters,$http){
            return BDParameters.then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                if(result["selectorList"] === 0)
                {
                    return "";
                }
                else
                {
                    //return Routing.generate('_NRtworks_FlatView_DiscrimSelector');
                    return $http.get(Routing.generate('_NRtworks_FlatView_DiscrimSelector')).then(function(result)
                    {
                        console.log(result.data);
                        return result.data;
                    });                           
                }
            });
            //return Routing.generate('_NRtworks_FlatView_DiscrimSelector');

          }]                                                                     
      }
  }
```

});